# Parameter not respected in formula (in PyQGIS script exported from QGIS Processing model)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

To demonstrate my issue with `@parameter`s in formulas: I created a simple QGIS Processing model where an `input_layer` is buffered with `buffer_distance`. In addition the `buffer_distance` should be written to a field with the following field calculator formula:

`'-' || @buffer_distance || '-'`

[image: the simple processing model]

Running the model with `buffer_distance=50` from within QGIS (v3.32) works as expected, the geometries are buffered and a new column contains the values `-50-`.

However, when exporting the model to a python script the formula apparently does not work anymore. Buffering still works, but the new column only contains `NULL` values:

```py
"""
Model exported as python.
Name : parameter_test
Group : gis.stackexchange
With QGIS : 33203
"""

from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterNumber
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
import processing


class Parameter_test(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterNumber('buffer_distance', 'buffer_distance', type=QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Double, minValue=0, maxValue=100, defaultValue=50))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('input_layer', 'input_layer', defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Output_layer', 'output_layer', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, supportsAppend=True, defaultValue='TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(2, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Buffer
        alg_params = {
            'DISSOLVE': False,
            'DISTANCE': parameters['buffer_distance'],
            'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,  # Round
            'INPUT': parameters['input_layer'],
            'JOIN_STYLE': 0,  # Round
            'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
            'SEGMENTS': 5,
            'SEPARATE_DISJOINT': False,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Buffer'] = processing.run('native:buffer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Field calculator
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD_LENGTH': 0,
            'FIELD_NAME': 'parameter_check',
            'FIELD_PRECISION': 0,
            'FIELD_TYPE': 2,  # Text (string)
            'FORMULA': "'-' || @buffer_distance || '-'",
            'INPUT': outputs['Buffer']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Output_layer']
        }
        outputs['FieldCalculator'] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Output_layer'] = outputs['FieldCalculator']['OUTPUT']
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'parameter_test'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'parameter_test'

    def group(self):
        return 'gis.stackexchange'

    def groupId(self):
        return 'gis.stackexchange'

    def createInstance(self):
        return Parameter_test()
```

I was able to fix the problem by replacing the original formula using the at notation (`@parameter`) with an f-string where I manually set the parameter value:

```py
# "FORMULA": "'-' || @buffer_distance || '-'",
"FORMULA": f"'-' || {parameters['buffer_distance']} || '-'",
```

Should the `@` notation work? Or did I stumble upon a bug / limitation of the python script export?

Comment: In your field calculator, you have 'FIELD_LENGTH': 0, Is this correct? Have you tired changing this? Also if it is a buffer distance, should it not be numeric instead of text?

Comment: @Walshe_d thanks! The `buffer_distance` input is indeed numeric (and buffering works). The python script also works with `FIELD_LENGTH` 0 (unlimitied afaik) - if I change the formula as mentioned above. So I think the problem lies elsewhere.